# How to convert a number 30.006649999999994 to 30.01 in js?

Tags: javascript, math

Anyone knows such a function in javascript?

Comment: How about if( x == 30.006649999999994) x = 30.01;  It will work exactly as requested.

Comment: You're talking about rounding rules: does the midway point round up or down? It's important rounding work properly for all situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just choose your desired accuracy and use a multiplication/division together with `round` function.

In your case, if you want to round to second decimal digit you could do

```
Math.round(value*100)/100
```

Comment: This can fail for large values where the `*100` causes precision to be lost. eg. `Math.round(100000000000000.33*100)/100` returns `100000000000000.31` despite `.33` being representable as a float.

Answer (score 5):

```
num = 30.006649999999994;
result = num.toFixed(2); // result will equal 30.01
```

Here's a [sample of this code over at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ulunu5/edit)

Comment: Unfortunately, `toFixed()` is crazy broken in IE. eg. `(1.9).toFixed(0)` is `2`, but `(0.9).toFixed(0)` is `0`

Comment: @Ivo: thanks for the downvote! The answer was solely to illustrate to the questioner how to perform the **rounding** being sought. I hadn't claimed it'd return a numeric value. Perhaps you'd like to go downvote the other `.toFixed` solutions. That'll make yourself feel better about nitpicking answers on StackOverflow. Have A Nice Day!

Comment: I'm not nitpicking here, it's just that the opener does not seem to have much clue about what he is doing. So not telling him that it will return a string, will just make him wonder why `result + 2` doesn't work the way he expected it to.

Answer (score 2):

I always use my own round function for that.

```
function round(value, precision){                   
    if(precision){                                               
        var exponent = Math.pow(10, precision);                  
        return Math.round(value * exponent)/exponent;           
    }else{                                                       
        return Math.round(value);                               
    }                                                            
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
round(30.006649999999994, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 30.006649999999994;
num2 = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rated up the answer by p.campbell, it doesn't look like I can comment on someone's answer yet.

But all you need to make that a number is add parseFloat();

num = 30.006649999999994;
result = parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)); // result will equal 30.01

Comment: Is it any shorter? No. Does it still invoke unnecessary type conversion? Yes.